# Double 'in' in one sentence

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Is the sentence below correct? I want to use the phrasal verb **to stay in** and the adverbs **in the evening**. I know how to write the sentence in different forms but I ask you if the form below is correct.

> I'm going to stay in in the evening.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's a little bit awkward, but it's not incorrect.

Comment: he said that that was his house.

Comment: :) WOW. That's very good.

Comment: I would choose a different way of writing this sentence like "I'm going to stay in this evening", but it is not incorrect. As the other answers have stated there are examples in English of this construction, but I think it's generally to be avoided.

Comment: Your example should be "I'm going to stay in *for* the evening." See [*for*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for_1): "4. over a span of (time or distance)"

Comment: "It is true for all that, that _that_ 'that' that _that_ 'that' signifies is not the one to which I referred"  :) https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Power_of_7/7_Thats_2948.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it clearer to the reader, you should use a comma between the repeated word.

Using Andrews example:

> Please stand by, by the phone.
>   Would you like to hang out, out of the house?

And your original one:

> I'm going to stay in, in the evening

Comment: To me at least, this seems like an unusual use of punctuation. I've never seen a book on grammar that suggested this, nor have I seen it in writing.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the dash, but a comma is fine.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, this is perfectly correct.  It's not uncommon to say things like this when speaking naturally, and you find yourself using a verb with a preposition (like "stay in") along with an adverb of time or place (like "in the evening").  If you're quick (and you care about such things) you could replace "in the evening" with "this evening" and avoid the double "in", but generally no one will care.

Other examples:

> Please stand by by the phone.
>
> Would you like to hang out out of the house?
>
> In the evening traffic tends to ease off off of the main roads.

And many others.

Comment: How about "traffic tends to ease off off off-ramps?"

Comment: @supercat Yep!  Or you can add an "of" in there "traffic tends to ease off off of off-ramps".  Say that three times fast.

Comment: "Traffic tends to ease off off of off-ramps."  I am finding that that is a difficult thing to say.

Comment: @Andrew In Australia we tend not to say _off of_, but just _off_, so that will appear normal to some people.

Comment: @CJDennis  In the US we also say either "off the main roads" or "off **of** the main roads".  I just added the "of" for clarity.  Plus "ease off off of off-ramps" is more of a tongue-twister.  :)

Comment: Are we really going to discuss what John had had had had had had, or how Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo?